# My responsive nav bar not working and anchor tag also

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Before I added the pic and paragraph the navigation bar was working and the login was also working on mobile veiw but its not working now. it's working on desktop. But after Adding the image and paragraph the navigation bar and login anchor tag not working.pls help
I have changed nothing in the CSS code of the nav and anchor tag
HTML

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color:#e3e1dc;
  

}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 80px;
  width:1100px;
 
}

nav ul {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

nav ul li a {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

nav ul li a:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  background-color: white;
  transition: transform 0.4s linear;
}

nav ul li a:hover:before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: right;
}

label #btn,
label #cancel {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}
.gif {
width: 1100px;
height: 300px;
}
li {
border-color:black;

}
.p {
position:absolute;
left: 800px;
top:30px;
color:white;

}
.png {
width:1200px;
height:600px;
position:absolute;
top: 250px;
right:-12.5%;
border-radius:30px;
overflow:hidden;

}
.tune {
position:relative;
top:200px;
width:900px;
left:70px;
border-radius:4px;
border:5px solid grey;
border-top:none;
background-color:white;

}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  ul {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: left;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    
  }
  li {
    position: relative;
    left: 65px;
    
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  label #btn {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  #check:checked ~ ul {
    left: -5%;
    
  }
  .gif {
  position:relative;
   width:138.5%;
   height: 470px;
   top:-130px;
  }
  nav {
  width: 138.5%;
  }
  .p {
  left:80%;
  top: 30px;
  color:white;
  border-radius: 29px;
  border-color:black;
  }
  .png {
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 150px;
  right:-4.5%;
  border-radius:30px;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
.tune{
width: 300px;
left: 30px;
top: -235px;
}
  
  
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Organic Pe|Home</title>
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="index.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" >
  
  
</head>
<body style="width:75%; max-width: 980px;" >
<nav>
<a class="p" href="../login/index.html" >Login</a>
 
 
  <label for="check">
    <i class="fa fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <ul>
    <li class="like" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="like"><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
    <li class="like"><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    <li class="like"><a href="#">Vote</a></li>
    <li class="like"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<img class="gif"src="pe.png">
<div >
<img src="ann.png" class="png">
<p class="tune">
<strong>Hello Everyone</strong></br>
We are very happy to announce that we are going
to release our Skyblock server very soon and the
server will have alot of features:<br>
=>Boss fight<br>
=>Pvp fight<br>
=>Economy<br>
=>Custom skyblock<br>
=>Custom shops<br>
=>custom npc<br>
=>Events<br>
=>Giveaways<br>
and alot more<br>
<br>
Thanks,<br>
Reyyan The OWNER,

        
        
</p>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please show us your JavaScript Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your image gets above the navbar.
This happens because your image has a "position relative" that gives "priority" to it.
One way to fix that is by adding a position to your navbar and utilize the z-index property to give it a greater "priority".
I hope that this can help you:

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    background-color: orange;
    height: 80px;
    width:1100px;

    z-index: 111
}
```

Comment: But mine work with-100 and I wrote nav{ above .gif